# Using a Matrix of Indices to Construct a SIFT Feature Vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sift

I am attempting to elegantly construct a SIFT feature descriptor as described in Lowe's [paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) in MATLAB. Most of the methods that I have seen have been rather messy, and I want to find an elegant way of doing this. I have my keypoints as interpolated (x,y) coordinates, and I have determined the gradient magnitude and orientation at all pixels in my image using:

```
[Gmag,Gdir]=imgradient(image)
```

I can easily find the 16x16 window of the gradient about each keypoint by slicing `Gdir`. I now need to build the histograms of each cell. I use the following code to get a bin number for each orientation/magnitude:

```
binned=discretize(local_Gdir,[-180:45:180])
```

`binned` is now a matrix of indices corresponding to the feature vector for each cell (it is filled with numbers 1-8; the indices of the `binned`  correspond to the local gradient indices).

In order to build the 128 element feature descriptor, I need to determine the feature vectors (histograms) of the 16 cells. I have been trying to split the `binned` matrix into the 16 cells while preserving the indices so that I can quickly refer to the local gradient magnitude matrix to sum the gradients in each bin for each cell before appending them into the final descriptor, but I can't find a clean way to do this.

How can I use the matrix of indices to build the 16 feature vectors of the 16 cells? Perhaps more generally, what is a good way of splitting an index matrix into sixteen submatrices without losing the original row/column indices?

Answer (score 0):

there are 16 number of 4 * 4 subwindow in the 16 * 16 window and  all elements of the 16 * 16 window have values form 1 to 8  so fo each subwindow separately a histogram should be created. This means that in a loop the `hist` function 16 times should be called.

Instead we can add a number to each subwindow ,then values of each subwindow become different than other sub windows.

for example for the first subwindow we add 0 to the binned value so values range from 1 to 8.

for the second subwindow we add 8 to the binned value so values range from 9 to 16.

for the third window add 16 .....

Then only one time the `hist` function will be called and 128 values computed.

```
% exmaple of a 16 * 16 window
binned_16 = randi([1 8],16 ,16);
% the values to be added to each 16* 16 window ;this matrix only one time needs to be computed
values_to_add = kron(reshape((0 : 15), 4, 4)*8 , ones(4));
% values added to the window
binned_added_values = values_to_add + binned_16;
% histogram computed
h = hist(binned_added_values(:), 1:128);
```